# Turning an NSString to an Integer and checking whether it is less than or equal to a value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsinteger

I have a project that returns a distance as an NSString. I want to check that distance to see if it is less or equal to, or more than 10,000 feet. I am running into an error that says "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC." Does anyone know how to convert the NSString into an Integer? or how to construct the code? Thank you!

```
- (IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender {

NSString *distanceInFeet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           stringForKey:@"distanceInFeet"];

if ([distanceInFeet intValue] <= 10000)
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" message:@"Distance is close" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;

else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Far" message:@"Distance is far" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply try this one?

```
if ([distanceInFeet intValue]<=10000)
{
```

OR

```
if ([distanceInFeet integerValue]<=10000)
{
```

EDIT:

As per your edit of code, and correct error shown...

```
NSString *distanceInFeet = [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           stringForKey:@"distanceInFeet"]];
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason that but of code doesn't seem to be working. It says everything is less than 10000. Any ideas why?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Does the fact that its an NSString have anything at all to do with it?

Comment: try nslog-ing distanceInFeet, and check whether it has some value or not?

Comment: i am able to return it in an alert just fine. its quite strange

Comment: surprised... now try to log [distanceInFeet className]

Comment: or your string contains some special characters in between, like comma ?

Comment: nope. can't put my finger on it. the string just returns a straight number. thats it

Comment: can you share your code ? or can i use your system through teamViewer?

Comment: "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' And your Heading is just opposite of this.... :(

Comment: First I tried to convert string to int, now i got that your problem is in converting string to int... kindly check the updated code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21214/discussion-between-brandon-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNumberFormatter`, it will return nil if the string is not a valid number.

```
NSString *distanceInFeet ...
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *distanceInFeetNumber = [numberFormatter numberFromString:ditanceInFeet];

if ([distanceInFeetNumber intValue] <= 10000) {
    //do stuff in here
}
```

Comment: distanceInFeetNumber is a pointer. You can't compare it with int.